# Too few arguments to function App\Models\Task::__construct(), 0 passed on line 26 and exactly one

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to access my task models within a controller using php slim but im getting this error

`Too few arguments to function App\Models\Task::__construct(), 0 passed on line 26 and exactly one on TodoController.php`

Any suggestions ? thanks in advance, i referenced similar questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071774/too-few-arguments-to-function-db-construct-0-passed-in) but i couldn't tie it into what i had.

Ultimately i want to pull in methods from the Task.php model and call it in the controller when needed.

the TodoController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

use App\Models\Task;

class TodosController extends BaseController
{

    // public function getTodos($request, $response, $args)
    // {
    //  $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY task");
    //  $sth->execute();
 //         $todos = $sth->fetchAll();

 //        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', ['todos' => $todos]);

    // }

    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = new Task();
        $tasks->getTodos();


    }

    public function deleteTodo($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=:id");
        $sth->bindParam("id", $args['id']);
        $sth->execute();
        $todos = $sth->fetchObject();
        $url = urlFor($todos);
        var_dump($url);
        return $this->response->withJson($todos)->withRedirect('/todos');


    }
```

And if this helps here is my Task.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Slim\Views\Twig as View;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class Task
{

    protected $c;
    public $db;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->c = $container;
        $this->db = $container['db'];

    }

   public function getTodos($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY task");
        $sth->execute();
        $todos = $sth->fetchAll();

        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', ['todos' => $todos]);

    }




}
```

I also viewed another similar example [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597996/slim-model-db-instance), however still couldn't understand what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Pass something as an argument to `new Task()`

Comment: like what  ? im a bit new to this sorry.

Comment: `public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)` << parse container when you call `new Task()`

Comment: @nogad don't know what to pass in the parameters

Comment: @nogad I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index($req, $res, $args)
{
    $tasks = new Task($this->container);
    $tasks->getTodos($req, $res, $args);
}
```

Comment: Some explanation must be provided, so that OP had chance to learn.

Comment: i ended up using eloquent models its alot more simpler. but thanks anyways